# C# PrintPage function from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

**Problem**

I have an issue with moving the PrintPage function *(SampleForm_PrintPage)* to a new class *(PrintPageDesign)* also design of the PrintPage uses data from the main form and i have not been able to pull the data in to the new class.

**Why?**

I'm moving all PrintPage functions to individual classes as there are multiple page designs required in the application, having them all in the same main form seems hard to review and update when each page design requires any change.

**Sample Code**

To simplify my problem i have created a sample solution in visual basic,

[image: Sample Print]

Form1.cs (form code):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sample_Print
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BTN_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog PD_SamplePage = new PrintDialog();
            PrintDocument Doc_SamplePage = new PrintDocument();
            Doc_SamplePage.PrintPage += SampleForm_PrintPage;
            PD_SamplePage.Document = Doc_SamplePage;
            Doc_SamplePage.Print();
        }

        protected void SampleForm_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(TB_Name.Text.ToString(), new Font("Roboto Condensed",12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
        }

    }
}
```

**Requirement**

i would like to move function
***SampleForm_PrintPage***
to class **PrintPageDesign** , currently there is only visual studio generated code is in the class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample_Print
{
    class PrintPageDesign
    {
    }
}
```

i have tried several ways to get the value from the text box outside of the main form but resulted in null.

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `public class PrintPageDesign(string someString) { ... }` -> `var pageDesign = new PrintPageDesign(TB_Name.Text);` -- Most of the *HighQuality* settings you have in `SampleForm_PrintPage` are useless. In this context, all of them. -- You may find out that you need to pass more than a string to the constructor of that class. When this happens, build specialized class objects that contain all the data needed to print a page and pass these objects to each related printing class that needs that data.

Comment: It's not clear from the tags you have set what is the Version of Visual Studio in use. Anyway, this question is not related to Visual Studio, per se. -- Remove tags that are not related to the question and maybe add those that are, as `printdocument`

Comment: @Jimi I'm using Visual Studio 2019 community edition.

Comment: You can separate the different printing designs and logics in [partial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) classes. You can access your `Main` Form controls and members from a partial class and print out their values.

Comment: @dr.null how would i call Textbox from the main form in the new partial class PrintPageDesign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, you can use partial classes to separate the `Main` Form members, methods and functionalities.

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to add a new class. Rename the file to `PrintPageDesign` and hit **Add**.
- In the new class, add the `partial` modifier and change the name to `Main` (the exact name of the main Form). Note, we are creating a *partial* class here and not *deriving* from the `Main` form.

Now you are within the `Main` Form context and you can access its members.

---

**Example**

The **Main** Form class:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sample_Print
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BTN_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => PrintJob1();
    }
}
```

The **PrintPageDesign** class:

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Sample_Print
{
    partial class Main
    {
        private void PrintJob1(bool preview = false)
        {
            using (var doc = new PrintDocument())
            {
                doc.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
                {
                    var g = e.Graphics;
                    var r = new Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.X, e.MarginBounds.Y, 
                        e.MarginBounds.Width, 32);

                    using (var sf = new StringFormat())
                    using (var fnt = new Font("Roboto Condensed", 12, FontStyle.Bold))
                    {
                        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                        g.DrawString(TB_Name.Text, fnt, Brushes.Black, r, sf);
                        r.Y += r.Height;

                        foreach (Control c in Controls)
                        {
                            g.DrawString(c.Name, fnt, Brushes.Black, r, sf);
                            r.Y += r.Height;
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                };

                if (preview)
                    using (var ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog() { Document = doc })
                        ppd.ShowDialog();
                else
                {
                    using (var pd = new PrintDialog() { Document = doc })
                    {
                        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            pd.Document.Print();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```