# How do I go about separating code away from the main form class?

Tags: c#, forms, methods, scope

I'm only fairly new to C# but have a bit of a project on the go and have run into a bit of trouble.

I'm trying to follow (my known) best practices and want to get on top of this early.

Below is a very simplified example. I want to extract the methods, preferably to another file, but am having trouble scoping back to the original form.

```
namespace form_and_separate_class
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = GetText();
        }
        
        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetText();
        }

        public string GetText()
        {
            return "text111";
        }
        public void SetText()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Text222";
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to take the GetText() and SetText() methods out and put them somewhere else but still have them working.

I have done quite a bit of looking around online and youTube but it all seems a bit overcomplicated for me. Does anyone have any keywords (I thought it was method extraction) I need to Google or could throw a couple of lines in my sample above.

The form I'm trying to target is actually one which I have created through "Form form1 = new Form(); and even though the intellisence recognizes it, I can't get anything to work

thanks a lot!

I'm just trying to learn and get past this little bump in the road

Comment: What you would _actually_ want to do is bind that ui control's text property to a text property of a view model. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data/overview?view=netdesktop-7.0

Comment: [Partial Classes and Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods). SO [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72346997/14171304).

Answer (score -1):

If SetText() and GetText() methods are owned by your Form, and the specific textbox you are targeting is in that form, I don't think you can put these methods elsewhere (or maybe I didn't understand the question).

If you just need to organize your code in sections, you can take a look at C# regions.

Another option would be making these methods generic, something like:

```
public void SetText(TextBox textbox, string text)
{
    textbox.Text = text;
}

public string GetText(TextBox textbox)
{
    return textbox.Text;
}
```

In this way, you could put these methods in another class (maybe a static class) and use them adding a using directive at the top of your Form file.

Please try providing more details, I'll update my answer if needed.

Comment: yes that second option with the code seems to be the go. I did try calling a method and passing the form as an object parameter to the external method, but I wasn't sure it would work. would this approach allow me to use the methods declared on the original main form? that's what my overall aim is I'm pretty sure. thanks. sorry I can't even upvote your answer. lol

Comment: @Guy4678 Glad it helped you. I highly recommend you to take a look at fundamentals of object oriented programming. Learning the programming language really makes sense if you learn basic programming concepts first. If you need more help please let me know, I'm still not sure to have correctly understood your question as it is quite generic.